# Removing duplicate values from sql server on condition of 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
|Rownumber  |OldIdassigned  |commoncode  |
------------------------------------------
| 1         |FLEX           |Y2573F102   |
------------------------------------------
| 2         |RCL            |Y2573F102   |
------------------------------------------
| 3         |FLEX           |Y2573F102   |
------------------------------------------
| 4         |QGEN           |N72482123   |
------------------------------------------
| 5         |QGEN           |N72482123   |
------------------------------------------
| 6         |QGEN           |N72482123   |
------------------------------------------
| 7         |RACE           |N72482123   |
------------------------------------------
| 8         |CLB            |N22717107   |
------------------------------------------
| 9         |CLB            |N22717107   |
------------------------------------------
<b>| 10     |CLB            |N22717107   |
```

I need to delete the duplicate records based on Common code and a condition that - if oldidassigned is same then delete else don't delete.

For example Y2573F102 has 3 duplicate records rows 1,2,3 .... 1,2 need not to be deleted , only 3rd row has to be deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like updatable CTEs and window functions for this purpose:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by commoncode order by rownumber) as seqnum
      from t
     )
delete todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: @chadalavadaharish . . . I misread the question.  You state the condition is on "two columns".  But actually, you simply want the oldest record for the third column.  This is fixed by removing the second column form the `order by`.

Answer (score 2):

use window function `row_number`, according to your description and comments it seems you need change in partition clause

```
delete t
from
(select t1.*,row_number() over(partition by commoncode order by  Rownumber) rn from table t1
)t where rn<>1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eacc0688efb534a0addee68678f323fe

Comment: @chadalavadaharish https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5be60ae3135c6a767b4981723460b355 check this link

Comment: @chadalavadaharish does this your output Rownumber  OldIdassigned  commoncode
1  FLEX  Y2573F102
4  QGEN  N72482123
8  CLB  N22717107

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
DELETE t
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OldIdassigned, commoncode ORDER BY rownumber) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE t.seq > 1;
```

EDIT : If you want to check the duplication based on `commoncode` only then remove `OldIdassigned` from `PARTITION` clause :

```
DELETE t
FROM (SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY commoncode ORDER BY rownumber DESC) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE t.seq > 1;
```

Comment: @chadalavadaharish. . . I think you just need `commoncode` in partition clause.

Answer (score 2):

Use Row_Number()

```
delete t from 
(select *, row_number() over(partition by commoncode order by 
 rownumber) as rn) t 
 where rn<>1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all answers are similar (and correct), I will post one alternative way:

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM TableA AS A2
               WHERE A2.commoncode = TableA.commoncode
                 AND A2.OldIdassigned = TableA.OldIdassigned
                 AND A2.Rownumber < TableA.Rownumber )
```